# Using Anaconda Distribution, how to use bokeh plotting?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ipython, bokeh

*Note from maintainers: This question concerns the obsolete first generation Bokeh server. For details about modern Bokeh server applications, see:*

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

---

---

***OBSOLETE:***

I downloaded the Anaconda installer for Windows 32 bit from https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

In my Jupyter Notebook, I inserted code from here:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/demo/examples/plotting/server/remotedata.py

Executing in the notebook draws that error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-376-39dc49ee6c7a> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 from bokeh.transforms.line_downsample import downsample
      3 
      4 from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL, FB, GOOG, IBM, MSFT
      5 from bokeh.plotting import *

ImportError: No module named transforms.line_downsample
```

Shouldn't be everything delivered with my Anaconda install? How do I get it running?

Answer (score 2):

Also, note that the example you're looking at is actually on a branch, where the downsampling work was being developed.  This work is currently (this weekend) being merged into master, and will then be available in a cleaner form off of master.

So, if you want to just play with other bokeh examples, you can use `conda` to install the latest bokeh via `conda update bokeh`.  But if you want to run the above remote data example, you should do a `git clone` of that branch, and then follow the instructions in the Bokeh Quickstart to install it: http://docs.bokeh.org/docs/quickstart.html#quickstart

Comment: I took a look on that site but it wasn't clear to me where to enter those commands

Comment: Commands like `conda`, `git`, `pip`, etc. are all entered at the command line - either your Linux/Mac OS X prompt, or the Windows `cmd.exe` shell.

Comment: This seems not to be working for me (perhaps blocked by the IT of the company? "data =  self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize) socket.error [Errno 10054] An existing connection has been closed by the remotehost"

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the latest version of Bokeh ?
You can update your Anaconda installation using

> conda update conda

and then

> conda update anaconda

Comment: This looks like a linux command, doesn't it? Where should i type this into?